# How to join vertical and horizontal slick slider together

Tags: slick.js

I have to join two sliders in to one slider (thumbnails and big preview). At the mobile breakpoints it must be horizontal orientation for thumbnails and for desktop it must be vertical orientation for thumbnails.

initialization for big preview

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
```

initialization for thumbnails

```
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  arrows: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  vertical: false,
  verticalSwiping: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 992,
      settings: {
        vertical: true,
        verticalSwiping: true,
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

For instance, slider preview

Mobile
[image]

Desktop
[image]

Comment: So what's the problem you're encountering? This looks pretty straightforward.